# Remove punctuation, retain spaces, toLowerCase, add dashes succinctly

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to do the following to a string:

- Remove any punctuation (but retain spaces) (can include removal of foreign chars)
- Add dashes instead of spaces
- toLowercase

I'd like to be able to do this as succinctly as possible, so on one line for example.

At the moment I have:

```
const ele = str.replace(/[^\w\s]/, '').replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
```

Few problems I'm having. Firstly the line above is syntactically incorrect. I think it's a problem with `/[^\w\s]` but I am not sure what I've done wrong.

Secondly I wonder if it is possible to write a regex statement that removes the punctuation AND converts spaces to dashes?

And example of what I want to change:

`Where to?` = `where-to`

`Destination(s)` = `destinations`

`Travel dates?:` = `travel-dates`

**EDIT: I have updated the missing `/` from the first regex replace. I am finding that `Destination(s)` is becoming `destinations)` which is peculiar.**

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAdXJm?editors=0011

Comment: You forgot about the closing regex dellimiter `/` (in `/[^\w\s],`). Do you care only about ASCII punctuation? All from here - http://www.kerryr.net/pioneers/ascii3.htm? Try `.replace(/[!"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_\`{¦}~-]/g, '').replace(/\s+/, '-')`

Comment: `/[^\w\s]/g` you also forgot the global modifier on the first replace.

Comment: Regex just matches. I don't think you can match and replace different things in one statement...

Comment: About your edit - see evolutionxbox's comment. You don't get the replace of the `)` because you're missing the `g` flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex to only match ASCII punctuation and some symbols ([source](http://www.kerryr.net/pioneers/ascii3.htm)) - maybe we should remove `_` from it:

```
var punct = /[!"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]^`{|}~-]+/g;
```

or a more contracted one since some of these symbols appear in the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) as consecutive chars:

```
var punct = /[!-\/:-@\[-^`{-~]+/g;
```

You may chain 2 regex replacements.

```js
var punct = /[!"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]^`{|}~-]+/g;
var s = "Where to?"; // = where-to
console.log(s.replace(punct, '').replace(/\s+/, '-').toLowerCase());
s = "Destination(s)"; // = destinations
console.log(s.replace(punct, '').replace(/\s+/, '-').toLowerCase());
console.log(s.replace(punct, '').replace(/\s+/, '-').toLowerCase());
```

Or use an anonymous method inside the replace with arrow functions (less compatibility, but succint):

```js
var s="Travel dates?:"; // = travel-dates
var o=/([!-\/:-@\[-^`{-~]+)|\s+/g;
console.log(s.replace(o,(m,g)=>g?'':'-').toLowerCase());
```

Note you may also use [`XRegExp`](http://xregexp.com/) to match any Unicode punctuation with `\pP` construct.

Comment: Well, I think I adjusted the answer. Or do you want a version with a single regex? Note that to use `\p{P}` or `\p{S}` you need to use `XRegExp`.

Answer (score 1):

Wiktor touched on the subject, but my first thought was an anonymous function using the regex `/(\s+)|([\W])/g` like this:

```js
var inputs = ['Where to?', 'Destination(s)', 'Travel dates?:'],
    res,
    idx;

for( idx=0; idx<inputs.length; idx++ ) {
  res = inputs[idx].replace(/(\s+)|([\W])/g, function(a, b) {return b ? '-' : '';}).toLowerCase();
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += '"' + inputs[idx] + '" -> "'
        + res + '"<br/>';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id='output'></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The regex captures either white space (1+) **or** a non-word characters. If the first is true the anonymous function returns `-`, otherwise an empty string.

Comment: I understand "succint" as "short" - compare the length of the code with an anonymous method and with the chained `replace`s. Well, if you use arrow functions, it will look shorter.